# I try to make filename in upload_photo a global variable so I can use it in the add_client fuction but it throws an error filename is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def upload_photo(self):
    global img, filename
    global filename
    f_types = [('JPG Files','*.jpg'),("PNG File","*.png"),("All Files","*.*")]
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
    img=Image.open(filename)
    img_resized=img.resize((200,200))
    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)

    b2=Label(self.emp_Manage_frame,image=img,width=250,height=250,bg="red")
    b2.place(x=530,y=100,width=199,height=185)

def add_client(self):
    global img, filename
    global filename
    fob=open(filename, 'rb')
    fob=fob.read()
    data=fob
```

Comment: don't use globals use object attributes you'll have less problems

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error, and make sure your example shows how/when these functions are called.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You will get the error if the `add_client()` method is called before `upload_photo()`, but otherwise your code works OK. You *could* fix that problem by adding a `filename = None` at the top-level of the script to ensure that the variable is always defined — and the checked its value *before* attempting to use it.

However it would be even better to get rid of the global variables altogether because they are considered a [poor programming practice](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). The following shows how to implement that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.emp_Manage_frame = Frame(parent, width=800, height=640)
        self.emp_Manage_frame.pack()
        self.img = None
        self.filename = None

    def upload_photo(self):
        f_types = [('JPG Files','*.jpg'), ("PNG File","*.png"), ("All Files","*.*")]
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
        img = Image.open(self.filename)
        img_resized = img.resize((200, 200))
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)

        b2 = Label(self.emp_Manage_frame, image=self.img, width=250, height=250, bg="red")
        b2.place(x=530, y=100, width=199, height=185)

    def add_client(self):
        if self.filename is None:
            messagebox.showerror('File not defined!', 'Please upload image file first')
        else:
            with open(self.filename, 'rb') as fob:
                data = fob.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    upload_btn = Button(root, text='Upload Photo', command=app.upload_photo)
    upload_btn.pack()
    add_client_btn = Button(root, text='Add Client', command=app.add_client)
    add_client_btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```